# How can I open a file and append an item to an existing list in Python

Tags: python, append

I am new to coding and stack overflow. I searched the site but couldn't quite find what I was looking for.

I am trying to open a file and then append an item to the existing list in that file. However it only seems to want to add the the items to an existing string in the list. So the list stays at one item and the string just continues to grow.

Here is my code so far:
    import math
    import statistics

```
def differential(score,course_rating,slope_rating):
    diff = (score - course_rating) * 113 / slope_rating
    return math.floor(diff*100)/100

def data_gather():
    score = int(input("Enter your score: "))
    course = float(input("Enter the course rating: "))
    slope = int(input("Enter the slope rating: "))
    return differential(score,course,slope)

with open("handicap.txt", "a+") as hc:
    hc.write("[],"
             .format(data_gather()))

scores = []

with open("handicap.txt", "r") as hc:
    scores.append(hc.read())`
```

Each time I run this code I want the end result of the user input which is a function, to be added to the list. preferably as an integer, but if it's a string I can solve that after, I just need each item to be it's own item first instead of being added on to one big string.

Thanks so much everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid having to write strings if you use [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html).

```
import cPickle

mylist = [1,2,3,'test','string']
with open('myfile.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    cPickle.dump(mylist, f, cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

To read and append to the file, do

```
item_to_append = 'append_string'
with open('myfile.pkl', 'rb+') as f:
    mylist = cPickle.load(f)
    mylist.append(item_to_append)
    f.seek(0)
    cPickle.dump(mylist, f, cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

If you want to see the result, open and read the file:

```
with open('myfile.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    saved_list = cPickle.load(f)
    print(saved_list)

> [1, 2, 3, 'test', 'string', 'append_string']
```

Comment: Thanks!! I as able to use this and be successful with a few minor tweaks. I am using Python 3 so just used pickle rather than cPickle. Also the last line of the read/append file just needed to be changed to "pickle.dump" rather than f.dump" but now it is working great!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a newline char (`\n`):

```
with open("handicap.txt", "a+") as hc:
    hc.write("[],\n"
             .format(data_gather()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("handicap.txt", "a+") as hc:
hc.write("[],"
         .format(data_gather()))
```

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish here. To use `format`. You need to use `{}`.

To fix your code:

```
import math 
import statistics

def differential(score,course_rating,slope_rating):
    diff = (score - course_rating) * 113 / slope_rating
    return math.floor(diff*100)/100

def data_gather():
    score = int(input("Enter your score: "))
    course = float(input("Enter the course rating: "))
    slope = int(input("Enter the slope rating: "))
    return differential(score,course,slope)

with open("handicap.txt", "a+") as hc:
    hc.write("{}\n"
             .format(data_gather()))

scores = []

with open("handicap.txt", "r") as hc:
    scores = [float(_) for _ in hc.read().split('\n')[:-1]]
```

The last line of code is to take out the last element (empty because we add a \n char every time) and convert to float.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I received an error when attempting to use this.
"ValueError - could not convert string to float

Comment: Maybe remove the `float(_)` part and look at you `handicap.txt` file? If you have written in the file before, there will be `[]` chars and prevent you from converting to floats. I suggest you delete the old file, add `print(scores)` at the end, and try again.